# BaseX Index or Query Optimization for Partial String Match

Tags: optimization, indexing, xquery, basex

I am currently having an issue where my BaseX query is taking a lot longer than it should to search through my dataset. The problem is that I am searching for the substring of a fixed length text field.  If I search for the exact string, for example, it returns in a matter of 6ms vs searching for the last 8 character of a 15 character string takes 5 sec.  I have tried writing the search 3 different ways and every time it takes 5 sec.  My concern is that it needs an index for the last characters and it only seems to allow for indexing of the full string.  Anyhow, here is some sample info:

xml:
    `<xmlfile><sometag>FIXED39LENGTH</sometag></xmlfile>`

query:
    `<result>{
    for $c in db:open('Test')
    where $c/xmlfile/sometag[text() contains text ".{6,6}9LENGTH" using wildcards]
    return <result sometag="{$c/xmlfile/sometag}"/>
    }</result>`

As for the "full-text" index, it would just be specified as "sometag".

Comment: I don't think there is any option for indexing by part of the content of an element. Your options would appear to be, either update the documents creating an attribute with only the portion of the strings you are searching for, or create an indexing database. There's an example of creating an indexing database in the [docs](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Indexes#Custom_Index_Structures).

Comment: I was starting to examine this approach, because of not being able to update the source xml files. I will report back when I can determine if this improves performance.

Comment: Does basex support using ends-with ?

Comment: "ends-with" returns in the same time as substring and the rest of the attempts.  I tried @chrisis suggestion and it dropped it to sub 10ms, which is acceptable. Thanks!